# Matching data inside an Array without Vlookup

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am trying to match the data in multiple files using arrays (because vlookup takes too long).

For example: I have 10 source files that have the information (each file a for different day). Each file has a number of items and each item have multiple information columns, as of a normal database.

```
File 1 - 20 of January
Item (identifier) Price Discount Quantity
A                  100     5       10
B                  80      6       15
C                  110     3       15

File 2 - 21 of January
Item (identifier) Price Discount Quantity
A                  95      3       5
B                  90      6       10
C                  120     4       20
D                  130     7       2

File 3 - 22 of January
Item (identifier) Price Discount Quantity
A                   70      11      35
B                   100     1       15
D                   45      17      25
```

My code gets this data and uses vlookup to match, as adds new source files, it increases the number of items in the output file (if a file does not have an item that was there in the past, the information simply counts as zero).

My output in excel is:

```
Tab 1 (price)
All the item Identifiers    20/01   21/01   22/01
A                            100      95     70
B                            80       90     100
C                            3        4      -
D                            -        130    45

 Tab 2 (discount)
All the item Identifiers    20/01   21/01   22/01
A                            5        3      11
B                            6        6      1
C                            110      120    -
D                            -        2      25
```

And so on.

First problem is that the items in each file are not the same (some may be added or excluded), and currently I am around thousands of items, each of over 15 columns of information.

Second is that, if I transform this information (each file separately) to an array, how can I match the information without the vlookup?

Lets say I go to the first file, transform to array, how can I match my item identifiers to get the information for each date and create the output?

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a pivot table to solve this problem.  Your data is essential tabular.  All you need to do is add another column  to each of the tables in the files, that extra column being "fileDate" or something similar.

Pivot Tables can be used to generate a whole variety of reports.  You'll not need to worry about lookups.   In expensive database packages pivot tables are known as OLAP cubes; Excel's pivot tables are a great inexpensive alternative.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

If I just add another column, I believe I don't get the full data in the worksheet. I will read more about pivot tables too make sure.

If I just add the data at it is, it becomes 3D, which is something I don't yet know how to manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you currently already posses a method to open and analyse seperate files?

In the case you want to speed up the vlookups in your code, one method could be to reduce the amount of vlookups you execute. If the number of columns in your datafiles are always the same (col1 = name, col2 = date, col3 = address, etc.) than you can consider using `MATCH` to find the row number of the Identifier of interest (e.g. A,B,C or D) first:

```
MATCH(identifier_address, array_of_interest, 0)
```

If you store this information in a column this should only be searched once.

Then for querying the values in your files, use the `ADDRESS` function to directly access the data for each of your columns (1-15), without having to use vlookup, in the following way:

```
INDIRECT("sheetname!" & ADDRESS(cell_with_match_result, 2))
INDIRECT("sheetname!" & ADDRESS(cell_with_match_result, 3))
```

etc.

edit. ofcourse you'd have to refer to the file / array in question. added the `INDIRECT` statement.

Comment: Thanks for the answer:

I tried the match function directly on the files, but the problem is, if I don't transform the file into an array, it still takes too long to read one by one, even for a couple of files (I currently have hundreds).

Since, as you stated the columns are the same, I was thinking about using the match function inside the array, to match the coordinates with the identifier, but I don't know if that is possible.